# Parse times with sub-microsecond resolution in Python (e.g. coming from .NET TimeSpan objects)

Tags: python, .net, timespan, timedelta

The resolution of the .NET TimeSpan object seems to be set to hundreds of nanosecond.

In Python, the `datetime.timedelta` object seems to be able to create time spans with resolution up to microseconds.

How can I parse a string representing a time span coming from .NET application (e.g.: `t = "00:00:00.1243965"`) in Python (3.x is fine)?
Do I have to write my own class?

Comment: .NET's `TimeSpan` maps to Python's `timedelta` type - not `datetime`.  But you'll still lose some precision (microseconds = 6 decimals, ticks = 7 decimals).  Is that important to you?

Comment: Yup, good point about `timedelta` - I'll modify the question accordingly. Unfortunately, having 7 decimals is quite a big deal for the application I am writing: it's a log parser and I do have to take into account the 7th figure too.

Comment: You do realize that the system clock on most computers is only accurate to about 10ms or so, right?  Unless you have to match exactly for equality comparison (such as using the timestamp as an ID), those decimal places are just noise data.  They don't accurately measure anything.

Comment: Yes, I do realise that. And in fact, I do have to match them against timestamps.

Comment: Ok.  Just checking.   I don't personally know of a Python equivalent to `timedelta` with higher precision than microseconds, but perhaps someone else will have an answer.  You may just need to do it yourself with strings and numbers.  Good luck!